# Struts 2.5 StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, struts2

I'm trying to setup a struts version 2.5 project.

But I always get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

After a while of searching I think that I have to copy some jars to a lib folder.

But I'm using maven and spring, so normally I didn't have to / want to copy some jars into folders, because maven managed them.

My question is now, how to setup this project without copying jars.

I'm using...

> - Eclipse IDE
> - Maven
> - Spring
> - Struts 2.5

Comment: Have you checked your project actual dependencies through the dependency:tree maven command? Maybe you can post the command resut here.

Comment: After your project is built, go into your EAR/WAR file(s), and check to see what classes physically exist in your build and/or where they're located.